# SQL Server Error [28000] - Cursed attempts to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server in a niche context

Tags: sql-server, unixodbc

To cut the long story short and be brief, I've been tasked with building a private-local web-app. Part of it requires collecting some data from an existing server.

Normally, pc's in the LAN connect to the server via a .NET app (each pc has its own installation), to do their work.
The server admin is outsourced so I tried going at it alone, to not produce unnecessary overheads. Same applies for the software used.

---

Starting with a Wireshark capture of a local pc during login and usage, I found the server's name, local ip address, the various databases on it, version of Microsoft SQL Server (12.0.2000), along with every query issued.

Any attempt to connect/login was a failure, leading me to examine further and discover that:

1. The .NET app does some weird SMB2 shenanigans before logging in.
2. The user's login credentials are irrelevant to the server as I've captured the RAW SQL query from the app to the server that requests, (GUESS WHAT?) the salt and hashed password to validate on client-side (I presume) if the credentials are valid...
3. That the app's default sql-connection-string uses the 'sa' user (you guessed it..) without a password.
4. That the same string's datasource/target/database is (drumroll...) the '(local)' setting.
5. That most probably 4 has something to do with 1, as the SMB calls included 'Create Request File:' + the app_name.exe
6. That 5 is probably irrelevant as right before the first captured SQL query (2), there's a login/auth back-forth resulting in a success/fail message, followed by the first query. same back and forth was observed in my attempts to connect to the server without the app.

---

I'm using a linux-mint laptop, connected to the server's LAN, same subnets and all. I'm using UNIXODBC through the command line. I have installed ODBC Driver 18.

My current command + connection-string (there have been many variations) is:

```
isql -v -k "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.x.x,1433;DATABASE=db_name;UID=sa;PWD=;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Trusted_connection=no;"
```

The returned error (6) is:

> "[28000][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'."

---

I'm bamboozled, if you have any ideas on how to approach this before resorting to contacting the admin or the app's developers. OR if you have a better idea on how to get the required data, I'm ALL EARS (eyes in this case).

PS: I apologise for any mistakes, first post, please let me know how to post better. Extra apologies for not keeping it short, There's lots of extra info I omitted as they seemed not important, but im happy to provide if needed! <3

Comment: It looks like connection is working but I doubt that the password is empty for the sa user. That's really bad idea. Perhaps C# injects the password by some DataSource magic. With that being said, did you try to omit PWD= value altogether? I think you should ask the db admin for a regular account anyway, because using sa is bad

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have tried that. As for the connection string, I retrieved it by decompiling the .NET app, but as I am not adept at C# there's a good chance I missed something obvious. To be honest my situation is a Russian nested doll of niches. I've since abandoned this approach and settled for a feature limited solution of the project without the data. I appreciate you taking the time <3